# Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField

Tags: android, react-native

i am working on a react native android project but i am stuck on this error

```
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

D8: Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField    

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

i have tried to change multi dex to false in build.gradle

```
  defaultconfig {...
    multiDexEnabled false 
     ...}
```

i dont want to migrate to androidx , i just want to get rid of androidx & this error ;
please help me , thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No i started project from scratch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my research couldn't not find an easy way or should I say a correct way to draw back from androidx, to solve the above issue just add the following to your **gradle.properties**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

That might cause another issue like

> Execution failed for task
>   ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57_5DebugJavaWithJavac'

the reason of this error, if it occured, after migrating your android project to androidx, many of your react-native libraries ship native Java code and have not been updated, updating it manually is tedious, I was able to do so by using this library [jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier) simply by running

```
npm i --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
```

In my case there were still some libraries causing some issues such us react-native-fast-image, as a workaround, I created a gradle.properties inside /node_modules/react-native-fast-image/android and deactivated AndroidX and Jetifier for this module:

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

Comment: npx jetify results in "system cannot find the path specified" , what should i do ?

Comment: please checkout this issue raised on github https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier/issues/16

Comment: And what if we don t want to update to Android X because of too much conflict.. .?

Answer (score 3):

The answer that Ahmed posted is a great solution once you've migrated to AndroidX. In my case I found out that only one library in my application was using AndroidX from [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25293) thread

In short my solution was to simply yarn upgrade react-native-device-info@latest The app build as expected after rebuilding it

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click on Refactor on the top menu bar
3. Click on Migrate too AppCompat

I hope this shall help you

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem: I'm updating an app for RN 0.60.0. In my case, I had a dependency in build.gradle with a '+' in its version, and that particular dependency got updated, which broke my build.

In my case, explicitly specifying the version number resolved my problem.

`./gradlew app:dependencies` will show a tree of your dependencies; this might point you in the right direction as well.